# How to control nokia 5110 display using esp-01

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I am working on a smart device using esp-01 to pull data from internet and display on Nokia 5110 LCD display, and send back the resistive touch inputs to my server and display those on my lcd I am using an Arduino UNO as a secondary device that talks to esp-01, my display and the resistive touch panel. As the esp-01 has got a system on chip, I can program it and do most of the thing my UNO is doing, but because of lack of ports I am using UNO (as far as i know that's the only limitation.. I dont exactly know how is the analog pins on UNO different from the gpio pins on esp) is there any ways if I can do the whole task using only my esp-01 by eliminating UNO. If its only about the less gpio pins on esp-01, will I be able to eliminate UNO by using higher esp such as esp-07 or esp-12E? if not, could you suggest a best way of bi-directional communication between esp and UNO? (so that esp can sent the display info to uno and based on that info, uno can send the resistive touch inputs to esp)

Comment: Your question consists of multiple questions tossed around informative text. Also, it consists of multiple questions which are merely related and does not involve any schematics or diagrams to make visible what you mean. Try to make your question more concrete.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a NodeMCU ESP12E board for example as a standalone microcontroller, you actually don't need an Arduino in your case.

Comment: Since the restive touch is connected on the analog inputs, will the esp still read the analog values?

Answer (score 0):

The ESP-12 (don't know about other versions) does have one ADC pin.
https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/doc/reference.md#analog-input

I don't know how much your pins display needs. If this is more than one, then you will need a seperate ADC. There are many available as a single chip, but you could also use an arduino as you're doing now.